# Split a text by a backslash \ ?

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

I've searched for hours. 
How can I separate a string by a "\"

I need to separate HORSE\COW into two words and lose the backslash.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - read the section that talks about escaping strings

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$array = explode("\\",$string);
```

This will give you an array, for `"HORSE\COW"` it will give `$array[0] = "HORSE"` and `$array[1] = "COW"`.  With `"HORSE\COW\CHICKEN"`, `$array[2]` would be `"CHICKEN"`

Since backslashes are the escape character, they must be escaped by another backslash.

Comment: I tried with \\ it simply returns the values HORSE\COW and "blank" as the two values.

Comment: Well, I assumed that the string was being pulled in from somewhere like a database, if not, the \ in the string must be escaped as well like: `"HORSE\\COW"`

Answer (score 8):

You would use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and escape the escape character (`\`).

```
$str = 'HORSE\COW';

$parts = explode('\\', $str);

var_dump($parts);
```

[CodePad](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5775431/edit).

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "HORSE"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "COW"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it:

```
$text = 'foo\bar';

print_r(explode('\\', $text)); // You have to backslash your
                               // backslash. It's used for
                               // escaping things, so you
                               // have to be careful when
                               // using it in strings.
```

---

A backslash is used for escaping quotes and denoting special characters:

- `\n` is a new line.
- `\t` is a tab character.
- `\"` is a quotation mark. You have to escape it, or PHP will read it as the end of a string.
- `\'` same goes for a single quote.
- `\\` is a backslash. Since it's used for escaping other things, you have to escape it. Kinda odd.

Comment: I ran the code from above with \\ and get HORSE\COW and [0] as the array elements. Must be a bug.

Comment: Did you use `$text = 'HORSE\COW';` or `$text = "HORSE\COW";`? The quotes matter.

Comment: I can confirm that the print_r(explode) example from above is working, however you forgot a ")" at the end.

Comment: Single quotes double quotes, same result. Text remains unexploded.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? This works perfectly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IqKhfU

Comment: Not worth it. I changed all of my text list data to have a "/" slash delimiter, explode now works.

Comment: The lesson here is don't build databases with \ and / (metacharacters) Use commas for crying out loud. Preg commands will haunt you in the night.

Comment: Lol, that's good. I've had that happen, but in my case I forgot a delimiter in the first place. It was all one big line...